# Instrument Java system class with byteBuddy

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, byte-buddy, javaagents

I am new to bytebuddy. I tried to follow [the link](https://gist.github.com/raphw/34c0e2fffe2ee7b4f02f) here to instrument a java system class, java.lang.String without success.  Below is the code,

```
       AgentBuilder agentBuilder = new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .ignore(ElementMatchers.nameStartsWith("net.bytebuddy."))
                .enableBootstrapInjection(instrumentation, temp);
        agentBuilder
                .type(ElementMatchers.nameEndsWith(".String"))
                .transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer() {
                    @Override
                    public DynamicType.Builder<?> transform(DynamicType.Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription, ClassLoader classLoader, JavaModule javaModule) {
                        return builder.method(ElementMatchers.nameContains("toString")).intercept(MethodDelegation.to(MyInterceptor.class));
                    }
                }).installOn(instrumentation);


public static class MyInterceptor {

    public static String intercept(@SuperCall Callable<String> zuper) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  Hacking!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        return zuper.call();
    }
}
```

from the ByteBuddy log, it seems the class has been transformed.

```
[Byte Buddy] DISCOVERY java.lang.String [null, null, loaded=true]
[Byte Buddy] TRANSFORM java.lang.String [null, null, loaded=true]
[Byte Buddy] COMPLETE java.lang.String [null, null, loaded=true]
```

After the instrumentation, when I invoke toString, for example,

`system.out.println ("testString".toString());`

I expect to see,

```
"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Hacking!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
"testString"
```

However, I only saw

```
  "testString"
```

Please let me know what the issue is. Thanks ahead.

Comment: use byte-buddy in version 1.9.3

Comment: You should be more specific on “But when run the test (what test), I did not see the expected (what did you expect) result (what actual result did you get).”…

Comment: @Holger, After the instrumentation, when I invoke toString, for example, system.out.println ("testString".toString()); I expect to see, "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  Hacking!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", then "testString"

Comment: the code above, only prints, "testString" in my test

Comment: You don’t get quotation marks in the output, do you? But anyway, perhaps `String.toString()` gets handled specially by the JVM, eliminating the call which is supposed to have no effect, without looking at the actual byte code.